# Can't reload the opened page in a Chrome App

Tags: google-chrome-app

I'm trying to update a page in a Chrome App but I get the error:

> Can't open same-window link to "chrome-extension://XXXX/page.html"; try target="_blank".

My `manifest.json`:

```js
"app": {
    "background": {
      "scripts": [ "background.js" ]
    },
    "persistent": false
},
```

my `background.js`:

```js
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
  chrome.app.window.create('page.html', {
    'outerBounds': {
      'width': 7000,
      'height': 7000
    }
  });
});
```

and a `window.location.reload();` in `page.js`

P.S.: I considered `chrome.runtime.reload();`, but it will restart the window/browser, I just wanted to refresh the page without the window closing and opening.

Comment: There's no way to reload app window. You can close it and show again.

Comment: I've created another page "main.html" and I'm loading the "page.html" from that one on an iframe and I'm able to reload it that way

Comment: That's quite creative. I think it'd be useful to others if you add it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created another page "main.html" and I'm loading the "page.html" from that one on an iframe and I'm able to reload it that way,

Just posting my own solution in hope that it might help someone.